# Abbreviate Array Indexing in Numpy

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have a function that takes an array as input. The array dimension lies between 1 and 4. I want to check if the first dimension is of length 2 and want to reduce it to 2 if the length is greater. What I am doing is:

```
if D.shape[0] != 2: 
   if D.ndim == 1:
       D = D[:2]
   elif D.ndim == 2:
       D = D[:2, :]
...
```

As you can see, this smells bad. So I wonder how to to something like
D = D[:2, ...

Answer (score 1):

`D=D[:2]` should be enough for all cases. The default is to take all the inner dimension objects (just like lists, just like arrays in other languages).

Comment: Wow. Okay that was too easy. Thank you :-D